# Mapping which holds and passes previous result

Tags: haskell, dictionary

When solving system of linear equations by [Tridiagonal matrix algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm) in Haskell I met following problem.

We have three vectors: `a`, `b` and `c`, and we want to make a third vector `c'` which is a combination of them:

```
c'[i] = c[i] / b[i], i = 0
c'[i] = c[i] / (b[i] - a[i] * c'[i-1]), 0 < i < n - 1
c'[i] = undefined, i = n - 1
```

Naive implementation of the formula above in Haskell is as follows:

```
calcC' a b c = Data.Vector.generate n f
  where
    n = Data.Vector.length a
    f i = 
      | i == 0 = c!0 / b!0 
      | i == n - 1 = 0
      | otherwise = c!i / (b!i - a!i * f (i - 1))
```

It looks like this function `calcC'` has complexity *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) due to recurrence. But all we actualy need is to pass to inner function `f` one more parameter with previously generated value.

I wrote my own version of `generate` with complexity *O*(*n*) and helper function `mapP`:

```
mapP f xs = mapP' xs Nothing
  where
    mapP' [] _ = []
    mapP' (x:xs) xp = xn : mapP' xs (Just xn)
      where
        xn = f x xp

generateP n f = Data.Vector.fromList $ mapP f [0 .. n-1]
```

As one can see, `mapP` acts like a standard `map`, but also passes to mapping function previously generated value or `Nothing` for first call.

My question: is there any pretty **standard** ways to do this in Haskell? Don't I reinvent the weel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two standard function called [`mapAccumL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) and [`mapAccumR`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumR) that do precisely what you want.

```
mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
mapAccumR :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
```

Basically, they behave like a combination of `fold` and `map`.

```
map   f   = snd . mapAccumL (\_ x -> (()   , f x) ()
foldl f b = fst . mapAccumL (\b x -> (f b x, () ) b
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After your comment I found prescanl function in Data.Vector library which seems to be a combination of my generateP and mapP.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Data.Array, which is lazy, you can express the recurrence directly by referring to c' while defining c'.

Answer (score 1):

Following code seems to be the simplest implementation of formula above in my case:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as V

calcC' a b c = V.postscanl' f 0.0 $ V.zip3 a b c
  where
    f c' (a, b, c) = c / (b - a * c')
```

Thanks to the authors of `Vector` who added helpfull `postscanl'` method.